# Extracting several arrays/lists from single array based on list of entry/outry indices without looping over indices

Tags: python

I want to extract several arrays or lists from a single array based on a list of indices. I know how to solve this looping over the indices:

```
import numpy as np

Data = np.arange(15)
in_list = [1,5,10]
out_list = [3,8,12]
interval = []
for in_ind,out_ind in zip(in_list,out_list):
    interval.append(Data[in_ind:out_ind])

>>> interval
[array([1, 2]), array([5, 6, 7]), array([10, 11])]
```

My "Data"-array is really large and my list of indices contains more than 10000 elements. It is therefore really time consuming to loop over the indices. How can I come to the same results without looping through the indices and/or calling the "Data"-array several times?

Answer (score 0):

For represent indices range need only first and last elements

```
in_list = [1,5,10]
out_list = [3,8,12]
interval = []
for in_ind,out_ind in zip(in_list,out_list):
    interval.append(range(in_ind,out_ind))
```

Next, elements between in_ind and out_ind will be evaluated only on iterating of concrete range value